# How to create summary data frame with all possibilities in R

Tags: r, join, outer-join, summary

If I have a vector of possible hours and possible items:

```
possible.items = c(12,13,14,15,16)
possible.hours = 0:23
```

And some data on customers who purchased those items at the hour they purchased them in:

```
frame = data.frame(id=101:105, hour=c(0,0,0,1,1), item=c(12,14,12,12,15))
```

How would I create a summary data frame that has a row for every possible hour, item combination filled in with the relevant number of rows from my data set?

I know how to create a summary data frame, but not one that includes rows that aren't in my original data set, "frame":

```
summary = aggregate(id~hour+item, data=frame, FUN=length)
```

I also see a way to get all possible combinations:

```
poss = merge(data.frame(hour=possible.hours), data.frame(item=possible.items), all=TRUE)
```

I am not sure how to combine the two. I also don't know if the path I am going down is correct.

I would like to get a data frame that looks like this:

```
hour item count
   0   12     2
   0   13     0
   0   14     1
   0   15     0
   0   16     0
   1   12     1
...
  23   16     0
```

Comment: The only thing I'm not clear on is how the "count" field is generated.

Comment: @BrandonBertelsen looks like it is the number of items sold within that hour.  Row 1 in the desired output represents `id` values of 101 and 103.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are almost there.  Merging by `hour` and `item` gives what you want.

With `poss` and `summary` as you have defined them:

```
result <- merge(poss, summary, by=c('hour','item'),all=T)
names(result)[3] <- 'count'
result$count[is.na(result$count)] <- 0

> head(result)
  hour item count
1    0   12     2
2    0   13     0
3    0   14     1
4    0   15     0
5    0   16     0
6    1   12     1
```

As in the comment (and suggested in Brandon's answer), `expand.grid` is the appropriate way to generate all combinations:

```
poss <- expand.grid(list(hour=0:23, item=12:16))
```

Comment: Ah, this works! Thank you! Do you think the way I started going about it is the correct way to think about it? It seems like maybe if I didn't generate poss and summary, I could do everything in less steps. It seems like maybe it could be done with only using one total merge operation.

Comment: You should use expand.grid to produce `poss`, which would be better than `merge`.

Answer (score 1):

This is how I would go about it using plyr

```
require(plyr)
purchases <- data.frame(id = 101:105, hour = c(0,0,0,1,1), item = c(12,14,12,12,15))
results.table <- merge(expand.grid(list(hour = 0:23, item = 12:16)), purchases, by = c('hour', 'item'), all = TRUE)
summary.table <- ddply(results.table, c("hour", "item"), summarise, count = length(na.omit(id)))
```

This way you don't need to create the possible.* and summary table first, saving a couple of steps.